# AWS Event Bridge schema types as lambda layer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-event-bridge, aws-lambda-layers

We are building a notification service using AWS EventBridge and different notifications will be sent depending on the event. We are thinking of a good way to share the type bindings for the event schemas among different teams/lambda functions. So we are considering to include the types as a lambda layer, but then the question is how to incorporate it into local development workflow. Is anyone doing this sort of things or any advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you expecting to need to support more than one lambda runtime or just one (i.e just python)?

Comment: Typescript and C# mainly. Would be nice to support python as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Lambda layer is simply a module/library in your application, in this way you be able to use in your local environment and implement in your Lambda like the other libraries and get an easier way to share with other Lambda functions in your account.

The way that you will implement this layer will depends of your technology, as we can see on this table:

[image]

And read more in this page [Creating and sharing Lambda layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html)

In your case, using a service like S3 or DynamoDB will be an easy way to manage this type binding/schemas, but this depends of data modeling/needs.